# Parse axios.get JSON Return for Display

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, axios, imgur

I'm trying to display some Images from imgur API.
I have made an axios GET request, and the request return an ARRAY.

[This the code with the request](https://hastebin.com/ugisaqenif.js)

This project is made with react native

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing with the response from the API. You need to assign the result of `getImageFrom` to `state.dataSource`.